# How do I add multi-line x-axis labels in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've made the following box plot chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0y0I.png

As you can see the x-axis labels overlap. How can I add line breaks to the labels?

I've tried to add the new line character in the actual strings like this:

```
xlab = [
    'Survey of Professional Forecasters -\nPCE Inflation Nowcast: 2019Q3', 
    'Survey of Professional Forecasters -\nPCE Inflation 1 Year Forecast: 2019Q3',
    'TIPS Spread'
    ]
```

But it doesn't change anything. I could just increase the size of the x-axis or use shorter labels but I'd rather just use line breaks tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.3.4, multi-line axis labels are still an [open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8169). For now you can [rotate the labels](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-orientation):

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
```

Comment: ahhh yes i hadn't thought of that. ty.